# HTML::Entities and encoding an apostrophe

Tags: perl, encoding, html-entities

I want to do something as simple as encode an apostrophe with its entity name *not its (hexa)decimal number*. However, it seems that HTML::Entities can't do this.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use HTML::Entities qw(encode_entities);

my $char = "'";

print encode_entities($char);
# &#39;
```

However, in the exported hash going from entity to character, the apostrophe is present as `apos`.

```
print $HTML::Entities::entity2char{'apos'}
# '
```

Why is it that for some characters the HTML entity name is not available? Or should it be forced, one way or another?

Comment: As far as I remember, not all of the entities have names. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML has a list.

Comment: Why do you want `&apos;` instead of `&#39;`?

Comment: @Borodin We are using some special characters as identifiers in filenames and it'd be nice to categorise them with a semantically transparent name. In other words, `apos` is much clearer than `&#39;`.

Comment: You could put it back into  `%HTML::Entities::char2entity` and hope that the browsers that use your page are well-behaved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character entity `&apos;` was introduced only in HTML5 and is invalid in HTML4 and earlier. Some browsers will not represent it correctly

The
[Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Entities_representing_special_characters_in_XHTML)
that **simbabque** links to
[in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43654004/htmlentities-and-encoding-an-apostrophe#comment74358284_43654004)
says this

> The use of `&apos;` or custom entity references may not be supported and may produce unpredictable results.

`HTML::Entities` takes the safe route of encoding it as `&#39;` which is valid in any iteration of the standard

The module uses a hard-coded hash `%entity2char`, and uses it to build the inverse mapping for encoding in `%char2entity`. The entry for the apostrophe is then explicitly deleted to force a numeric entity to be used

```
delete $char2entity{"'"};  # only one-way decoding
```

(The comment is in the original code)

If you are willing to commit to using HTML5 throughout then
I suggest that you use [`HTML::HTML5::Entities`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::HTML5::Entities) which is a
*"drop-in replacement for `HTML::Entities`"*
but provides for all the standard HTML5 entities, including `&apos;`